# Windows Explorer not showing files saved from WhatApp

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

My Windows Explorer (Win 10 64 bits bitlocker enabled) is not showing the files saved from whatsapp windows. What can I do about it? For example, if I go and try to save another file in whatsapp windows software it shows me directory and the already saved files. But those files/dir do not show in windows explorer!

UPDATE: so i've checked and:
The dir which I am saving the files is: D:\Documentos\Passo Fundo\Documentos\Seguro
I've a tjunction of something like that that points d:\Documentos\Passo fundo to d:\Passo Fundo.
If I go to the original path it shows the "seguro" dir. If I go thru the tjunction it is not showing the dir. Does this has anything to do with using bitlocker?

Comment: Are those files and folders hidden? Can you tell us the path to them?

Comment: I dont see a reason for whatsapp saving the files as hidden. I've tried a dir /AH in cmd and it doesn't show any hidden files. the path is: D:\Passo fundo\Documentos\Seguro. This folder SEGURO doesn't show up in Explorer.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Can you try with another File-Management Static Software Application? Can you install GHISLER_Christian's "_Total Commander_" Static Software Application?

Comment: Go into Control Panel (icon view) >File Explorer Options>View Tab> untick the box "show hidden files,folders and drives" hit OK.

Comment: I've installed TotalCommander but unfortunately it also doesn't show the DIR. The only place where the dir is appearing is in whatsapp Save As window.

Comment: So I've updated the OP with some more info I've discovered.

Comment: To us, this is the required way to work. The `D:\Documentos\Passo Fundo\ ` Path looks like a Link to us. It should not bear anything in it. In GHISLER_Christian's _Total Commander_ Static Software Application, it should be marked as a `LNK` and not as a `DIR`. Links should not contain something in them, but they should rather lead somewhere. Maybe you can provide us with some nice screen-shots so that we can really enjoy and rejoice.